# Why it my serializer does not recognize all fields when I send a json?

Tags: python, angularjs, json, django, django-rest-framework

Hello I'm working with an endpoint using django + django rest framework, it endpoint must receive an array objects with a file in every object and once received the file is sent to Amazon S3.

Note: Using python-cassandra driver.

My object is:

```
class Archivo(UserType):
    tipo_documento = columns.Text()
    llave_s3 = columns.Text()
    bucket = columns.Text()
    tipo_contenido = columns.Text()
    subido = columns.DateTime()

class Laboratorio(Model):
    certificado = columns.Set(columns.UserDefinedType(cassandra_types.Prueba))
    foto = columns.UserDefinedType(cassandra_types.Archivo)
    equipamiento = columns.UserDefinedType(cassandra_types.Equipo)
```

And my serializers:

```
class PruebaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    nombre = serializers.CharField()
    organismo = serializers.CharField()
    costo = serializers.FloatField()
    numero = serializers.CharField()
    norma = serializers.CharField()
    archivo = serializers.FileField(write_only=True,
                                    required=False,
                                    validators=[sav_validators.FileValidator()]
                                    )

class LaboratorioSerializerCreate(serializers.Serializer):
    certificado = cassandra_serializers.PruebaSerializer(many=True)
    foto = serializers.FileField(required=False,
                                 validators=[sav_validators.FileValidator(
                                     constants.ALLOWED_IMAGE_TYPES)]
                                 )
    equipamiento = cassandra_serializers.EquipoSerializer(required=False)
```

The problem is when I send request using a Angular Client throw a 400 Bad Request.
[image: Error]

Reviewing the request I received the next fields in a request:
[image: Fields]
[image: Fields2]

But I don't know why throw exception when I send the request.

Comment: Your serializer should have fields in Meta class. And did you tried to GET request?

Comment: Sorry my serializers have Meta class, yes in GET, DELETE and PUT Idon't have any problem, the problem is only when using this serializer with files.

Comment: So you can't post with file? Have you tried to post json using postman or something like this?

Comment: Yes when I send an array object in every object have a file is not possible the method POST. I test endpoint with postman without array object it working  but I need with array object. Temporarily I change `to_internal_value` method to manually change the information for the serializer to recognize.

Comment: Did you specify `multipart/form-data` content type in request?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner In Postman  I test request with form-data with same problem and Angular Client using a library for upload files.